# sd card not detected at all in linux

Tags: linux, fedora, sd-card, linux-kernel, fedora-22

My SD card reader is not detecting any SD card.  There is no output from `dmesg` when an SD card is inserted.  `df` does not detect anything and also nothing `in fdisk -l`.  Does linux support SD cards?  I am running Fedora 22 (kernel 4.2.6) an a macbook pro retina (2014, 11,1).

Also, the sd card reader device number (05ac:8406) does not show up anywhere in lspci nor lsusb.

Here is my lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Apple PCIe SSD (rev 01)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
06:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
06:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
06:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
06:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
```

and here is my lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:0259 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 05ac:8289 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Linux supports SD cards.  Verify that the card is good by testing it on another machine.  Verify that the reader is still working by testing it with a known-good card.

Comment: I've tested it on my mac partition and it works fine, it's just not being pickup in linux

Comment: Odds are decent that it'll work with an updated kernel. Give Fedora 23 a try?

Answer (score 0):

Please trying to format  this SD card in FAT32 FILE SYSTEM. I think it method will be work.

I m from windows.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).